# GWT get URL parameter containing #

Tags: javascript, url, gwt

I have an URL:

```
example.com/servletPath/something.html?a=b&c=FW:%20Merrill%20/%20Allegheny%20Deal%20#%20Q04117
```

I am try to get the mapping content of parameter c, but the result from

`Window.Location.getParameter("c")` is `FW: Merrill / Allegheny Deal`

It's supposed to be `FW: Merrill / Allegheny Deal # Q04117`

Any idea how to catch the # character? Thanks.

UPDATES: fixed the issue by calling encodeURIComponent() directly using JNI to get the encoded URI component.

Comment: you can't have `#` as a query param, since it defines a hash (aka fragment/ID). use `encodeURIComponent()` to safely ship the url, then you can parse it as expected.

Comment: normally you can directly obtain the # part by calling: window.location.hash in javascript, you can do the same by using some JSNI or Jsinterop